# jade template engine a href tag with button

Tags: pug

How can I link a button in jade template? I am trying to generate the HTML

```
<a href="create"><button type="button">create new post</button></a>
```

I tried

```
a(href="create") button "create new post"
```

which results in

```
<a href="create">button "create new post"</a>
```

If I change it to

```
a(href="create")button "create new post"
```

I get the error

```
logJs\views\posts\update.jade:7 5| block content 6| h1='creating new post' > 7| a(href="create")button "hello word" 8| form(name="add-post",method="post") 9| div.input 10| span.label title Unexpected token `tag` expected `text`, `code`, `:`, `newline` or `eos`
```

Comment: <a href="create"><button type="button">create new post</button></a>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need to use a separate line and the correct indentation. The jade code

```
a(href="create")
   button(type="button") create new post
```

results in

```
<a href="create"><button type="button">create new post</button></a>
```

Answer (score 4):

One more solution:

```
a(href="create"): button(type="button") create new post
```

It will work for you too!